Unable to update Application Load Balancer via UI anymore (unsupported field: "defaultRouteAction")
I'd like to use the Google Cloud UI to update my load balancer but after playing around with some settings, I reached a state where I can only update (or reset) it via the gcloud CLI.
It complains that "defaultRouteAction" is unsupported by the UI. How can I reset or update it to use "Redirect the client to different host/path" again via the gcloud CLI?



I was able to add a fake pathMatcher, which made it possible again to edit the load balancer again:
defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[YOUR_URL_MAP]
pathMatchers:
- defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[YOUR_URL_MAP]
  name: www
  pathRules:
  - paths:
    - /search
    - /search/*
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[YOUR_URL_MAP]

